# How to convert Lambda Expressions from diferent domains?

Tags: c#, lambda, expression, expression-trees, linq-expressions

I'm trying to convert a Lambda expression from a domain to another.
This is what I receive as parameter:

```
Expression<Func<Entities.UserRight, bool>> expression
```

And I should return ane expression of type

```
Expression<Func<UserRight,bool>>
```

Both UserRight and Entities.UserRight are same models, but belongs to diferent nugget packages.

I'm trying by:

```
public Expression<Func<UserRight,bool>> ConvertExpression(Expression<Func<Entities.UserRight, bool>> expression)
    {
        var resultBody = Expression.Convert(expression.Body, typeof(UserRight));
        var result = Expression.Lambda<Func<UserRight, bool>>(resultBody, expression.Parameters);
        return result;
    }
```

But I receive an error of InvalidOperationException

Comment: Ultimately you'll need to map the first one to the other as there isn't going to be a native conversion.

Comment: to do this you'd need to rewrite the expression tree from top to bottom; `ExpressionVisitor` is ideal for that, but you can't be naive about it, as it contains things like `PropertyInfo` / `FieldInfo` / `MethodInfo` tokens, which you would need to map to the *other* type; it is *possible*, but...

Comment: If you had variables of type `UserRight` (`ur`) and `Entities.UserRight` (`eur`) how would you convert one to the other?

Comment: @NetMage Maybe using AutoMapper, why?

Comment: Because if you can't simply cast from `eur` to `ur` variables, you can't do it in the Expression tree - you need to add the proper lambda framework to handle the conversion exactly as if you had variables. Consider converting a `Func<Entities.UserRight, bool>` to a `Func<UserRight, bool>` - you would need to wrap `feur` with a conversion lambda `ur => feur(ur.ConvertToEUR())`.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have two class Address1 and Address2 like bellow:

```
class Address1
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Detail { get; set; }
}

class Address2
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Detail { get; set; }
}
```

and whe have an expression for Address1 like this:

```
Expression<Func<Address1, string>> getCityName = ad1 => ad1.City;
```

We can change the expression to be usable for Address2 by an ExpressionVisitor:

```
public class ExpressionConvertor: ExpressionVisitor
{
    private ParameterExpression ad2Parameter;
    public ExpressionConvertor(ParameterExpression ad2Parameter)
    {
        this.ad2Parameter = ad2Parameter;
    }

    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        if(node is LambdaExpression node2)
        {
            var exp = base.Visit(node2.Body);
            return Expression.Lambda(exp, ad2Parameter);
        }
        return base.Visit(node);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {       
        if(node.Expression is ParameterExpression)
            return Expression.PropertyOrField(ad2Parameter, node.Member.Name);

        return base.VisitMember(node);
    }
}
```

and finally we use this class like this:

```
Expression<Func<Address1, string>> getCityName = ad1 => ad1.City;

var ad2Parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Address2), "ad2");
var convertor = new ExpressionConvertor(ad2Parameter);
var getCityName2 = (Expression<Func<Address2, string>>)convertor.Visit(getCityName);
var getCityName2Method = getCityName2.Compile();

var addr2 = new Address2()
{
    City = "MyCity",
    Detail = "My Address Detail"
};
var cityName = getCityName2Method(addr2);
Console.WriteLine(cityName); //MyCity
```